# UniSharp's Laravel filemanager paginator doesn't appear in modal

Tags: laravel

UniSharp Laravel filemanager paginator doesn't appear in modal.
In lfm.php

```
'paginator' => [
    'perPage' => 50,
],
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
 php artisan vendor:publish --tag=lfm_public
```

You must update CSS and js file in the public folder

See documentation https://unisharp.github.io/laravel-filemanager/installation